# Retrieving the XML child element name using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a requirement to retrieve the child element name ,not an element value.
I have attached my XML below.

```
 <TaskInfo>
    <Appid></Appid>`enter code here`
    <BusinessUnit></BusinessUnit>
    <Amount></Amount>
    ................
    ................
 </TasKInfo>
```

I want to retrieve the child element name of TaskInfo using Xpath like
Appid,
BusinessUnit,
Amount,
..
..

Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use local-name()

Answer (score 1):

### XPath 2.0 Solution

```
string-join(/TaskInfo/*/name(), ', ')
```

returns

```
Appid, BusinessUnit, Amount
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `name()` function:

- `name(/TaskInfo/*[1])` returns `Appid`
- `name(/TaskInfo/*[2])` returns `BusinessUnit`

  etc.